# Specify which protocol (802.11 a, g, or n) a WiFi NIC should use when manufacturer has not provided a way to do this

Tags: wireless-networking, wireless-router

I am using a wireless NIC, under Windows 7 as a software access point.  It is fairly recent hardware and specifications indicate that it is compatible with 802.11a/g/n.  I am deliberately not sharing the particular model because I am seeking answers that might be generic and therefore of wide use to other readers.

For various reasons (compatibility with other buggy devices being chief among them) I would like it to operate only as an 802.11a or 802.11g access point, and not as 802.11n.

There are generally two ways to specify which protocol a wireless NIC will use under Windows:

1. Under Device Manager-->Advanced tab, there will be an option permitting the band and/or protocol to be set.
2. The manufacturer provides software that will allow the protocol to be set.

I am using a device that fails on both point 1 and 2.  It seems that the manufacturer (TP-LINK in this case) has not provided this facility.  However, the card must be able to decide for itself which protocol to use, as it is compatible with all three.

This raises two questions:
How can I force it to operate using only the protocol of my choosing? 
 If there is no way to do this in Windows, is it possible in Linux?

Comment: There are only two bands available to IEEE 802.11: 2.4GHz and 5GHz.  Only a dual-band unit would offer band selection.  Single-band units (typically for 2.4GHz) will not have any nor require any band selection options.  Are you confusing "band" with "channel"?

Comment: @sawdust thank you for the clarification.  I have edited the question to change references to "band" to "protocol" as this more correctly describes what I am interested in.